# Spring batch inserts with IDENTITY generated id

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an app where I need to do batch inserts of data. I have read that spring data disables batch inserts for IDENTITY id generator. The data base I am using (MemSql) does not support sequence generation because hibernate issues Select from seq for Update and MemSql does not support select for update statement. Is there a way I can do batch updates using IDENTITY or should I use Uuid based primary key or is there any other way to create the primary key id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MemSql, but since it doesn't seem to support basic locking or sequences, your best bet probably is to use UUIDs.